# Twig iteration + bootstrap modal unknown behavior

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, twig

Im creating some Twitter bootstrap modals from a iteration of twig. I'm not doing nothing special here, just using the name of some fields as id, nothing else... but my modal show me something like this:

[image]

**Here is the code:**

```
{% for item in post.get_field('avances') %}
                <div class="modal fade" id="{{item.mes|lower}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="{{item.mes|lower}}">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="{{item.mes|lower}}">{{item.mes|capitalize}}</h4><!--Acá el mes-->
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="{{site.theme.link}}/static/img/6.gif"></a>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="{{site.theme.link}}/static/img/6.gif"></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="{{site.theme.link}}/static/img/6.gif"></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}

            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <hgroup><h2>Avances del Proyecto</h2></hgroup>
            </div>

            {% for item in post.get_field('avances') %}
                <a href="{{TimberImage(item.imagen).src}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{item.mes|lower}}"><div style="background:url({{TimberImage(item.imagen).src}}); background-size: 100%; background-position: center;" class="month col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <hgroup><h3>{{item.mes|upper}}</h3></hgroup>
                </div></a>
            {% endfor %}
```

**The output in the browser is completly insane:**

[image]

***But the weirdest thing is that the static test (whitout itaration) works perfectly:***

```
<div id="advance" class="row">
            <!-- Modal -->
            {% for item in post.get_field('avances') %}
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4><!--Acá el mes-->
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="{{site.theme.link}}/static/img/5.gif"></a>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="{{site.theme.link}}/static/img/6.gif"></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <a target="_blank" href=""><img src="{{site.theme.link}}/static/img/3.gif"></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}

            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <hgroup><h2>Avances del Proyecto</h2></hgroup>
            </div>

            {% for item in post.get_field('avances') %}
                <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><div style="background:url({{TimberImage(item.imagen).src}}); background-size: 100%; background-position: center;" class="month col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <hgroup><h3>{{item.mes|upper}}</h3></hgroup>
                </div></a>
            {% endfor %}
        </div><!--/.Advances Row-->
```

I tried some things and reviewd the code some times, but i can't get the problem... some idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're somehow outputting a gif image (according to the first GIF89a bytes)

Comment: Hm, ok the images are gif's but i just are using them in the src attr of the img element and the href. I'll try something